# Redux Toolkit w/ TypeScript: how can I properly type the return value from an async thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a async thunk like this

```
export const updateIndexingConfig = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/updateIndexingConfig",
  (config: UpdateIndexingConfigurationRequest) => {
    return sdkClient.updateIndexingConfiguration(config).promise();
  }
);
```

the update request can return an error message if there is any. The `updateIndexingConfiguration.promise()` is going to return a promise. And it is dispatched when user click on this button

```
<Button
  onClick={async () => {
    if (!isFormValid()) return;
    const updateIndexingConfigResponse = await dispatch(
      updateIndexingConfig(constructUpdateIndexingConfigRequest(indexingConfig))
    );
    if(updateIndexingConfigResponse.error) {
      // ... show error banner 
    } else {
      window.location.href = "#/settings/";
    }
  }}
>
  Update
</Button>;
```

TypeScript compiler is giving me this error on this line `if(updateIndexingConfigResponse.error)`  saying that

> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<any,
> UpdateIndexingConfigurationRequest, {}>'.

I think it is due to the SDK doesn't have the response type defined. but by reading its doc I know the response can have an error message when something goes wrong. so I quickly made one myself

```
interface UpdateIndexingConfigurationResponse {
  error?: {
    message: string;
  };
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

and I added it at the thunk

```
export const updateIndexingConfig = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/updateIndexingConfig",
  (config: UpdateIndexingConfigurationRequest): UpdateIndexingConfigurationResponse => {
    return sdkClient.updateIndexingConfiguration(config).promise();
  }
);
```

However the compiler is still not happy about it when I access `error` on the the returned response from the dispatch.

> Property 'error' does not exist on type
> 'AsyncThunkAction<UpdateIndexingConfigurationResponse,
> UpdateIndexingConfigurationRequest, {}>'.

Not sure what I am missing here. How can I properly type the response in this case?

Also a minor question, the TS compiler also yells to me at `await dispatch(updateIndexingConfig(...))`, saying that

> 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

but I know it indeed has effect. it does `await` in this case

Btw please don't question whether or not the code works, or even if `sdkClient.updateIndexingConfiguration(config).promise()` returns a promise or not, I tested it and I know it works. It is just the typing is missing and that is my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `dispatch` does not take types for thunks into account and thus the return type is typed incorrectly. Please use the actual `Dispatch` type from the store as decsribed in [the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks to me like your inner function may not be returning a Promise, which it needs to for createAsyncThunk to work.